# How do you add multiple python variables to a SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to make a SQL database in python that stores users names and birthdays. At the moment I have this code;

```
sql_command = ("""INSERT INTO birthdays(name, birthday) VALUES (%s,%s);""", (name, birthday))
cursor.execute(*sql_command)
```

But when I enter it, it gives me an error message. I have already created the database with the appropriate name and columns and I have defined the name and birthday variable. I am using SQLite 3. Any suggestions that anybody has would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use normal string interpolation instead of param substitution. Change `%s` to `?` as shown in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the %s to ? and it now works perfectly. This is the code I used;

**sql_command = ("""INSERT INTO birthdays(name, birthday) VALUES (?,?);""", (name, birthday))
cursor.execute(*sql_command)**